# Can a callout to C presize a Python dict's capacity?

Tags: python, dictionary, cpython

As an optimization for handling a dict which will hold tens or hundreds of millions of keys, I'd really, really like to pre-size its capacity... but there seems no Pythonic way to do so.

Is it practical to use Cython or C callouts to directly call CPython's internal functions, such as [dictresize()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Objects/dictobject.c#l592) or [_PyDict__NewPresized()](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Objects/dictobject.c#l686), to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by practical. It's certainly straightforward enough; you can just call `_PyDict_NewPresized(howevermany)`. Heck, you can even do it from Python:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> import sys
>>> ctypes.pythonapi._PyDict_NewPresized.restype = ctypes.py_object
>>> d = ctypes.pythonapi._PyDict_NewPresized(100)
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
1676
>>> sys.getsizeof({})
140
>>> len(d)
0
```

As you can see, the dict is presized, but it has no elements. Whether depending on CPython implementation details like this is practical is up to you.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping was possible, thanks! (Since I'm trying a possible optimization, it's practical enough to try a CPythonism, and fall back to normal behavior if unavailable.)

Answer (score 2):

After a night of hacking, I came up with the following solution which does not rely on any module. It allows you to initialize a dict with room for any number of elements up to 2**31-1 (=2,147,483,647).

```
def bigdict(size):
    bytecode = '\x91%c%ci%c%cS'%((size>>16)&0xff,(size>>24)&0xff,size&0xff,(size>>8)&0xff)
    return eval(bigdict.func_code.__class__( 0, 0, 1, 64, bytecode, (), (), (), "317070", '<module>', 1, '', (), ()))
```

As an illustration:

```
In [95]: print sys.getsizeof({})
280

In [96]: print sys.getsizeof(bigdict(0))
280

In [97]: print sys.getsizeof(bigdict(1))
280

In [98]: print sys.getsizeof(bigdict(100))
3352

In [99]: print sys.getsizeof(bigdict(2**29-1))
12884902168

In [100]: print bigdict(2**29-1)
{}
```

That is the slowest empty dict I've ever seen. That last command took ages to complete.

Comment: That's very interesting! Are such raw bytecodes portable between Pythons, or very implementation-dependent?

Comment: Python bytecode is typically not platform-dependent. It is often version-dependent, but I highly doubt this simple thing won't run across all CPython implementations, independent of version or platform.
I only used documented features for this. So me thinks even PyPy or Cython would run this. But I can't test it here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that's a bad idea, because it would mean that your code depends on the implementation of the python language. So it might break every time you update CPython.
However, there is a trick to pre-size a dict in CPython if you know the keys in advance (which might not extend to other implementations of python):

```
keys = {'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink', 'black'}
d = dict.fromkeys(keys)
```

This dict `d` [will have the correct size right away](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Objects/dictobject.c#l1378), because dict.fromkeys() allocates space in advance.

Comment: Alas, I don't in general know the tens-of-millions of keys in advance. But even if I did, or decided to use temporary placeholders just to trigger the dict-expansion, getting those keys into a giant set to use fromkeys() would likely involve the same sort of excess allocation/processing steps I was hoping to skip.